# Why isn't this a square? LWJGL

Tags: java, lwjgl

I have a basic LWJGL window set up and I am trying to draw a square using the `glBegin(GL_QUADS)` method. `Square square = new Square(25, 25, 25)`, is the way I am calling my Square class to draw the square... but it is a rectangle. When I call it I pass in all 25's as the parameters. the first two are the starting coordinates and the last 25 is the side length, as seen below. What am I doing wrong to produce a rectangle?

```
public Square(float x,float y,float sl) {
    GL11.glColor3f(0.5F, 0.0F, 0.7F);
    glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
        glVertex2f(x, y);
        glVertex2f(x, y+sl);
        glVertex2f(x+sl, y+sl);
        glVertex2f(x+sl, y);
    glEnd();
}
```

My Viewport code

```
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity(); // Resets any previous projection matrices
    glOrtho(0, 640, 0, 480, 1, -1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

Comment: Can you show your viewport code?

Comment: i have posted the code, thank you for taking the time to try and help

Comment: Anyway, you shouldn't use deprecated OpenGL

Comment: Yea... I used to have it drawing 2 right triangles but this was the code I had the most faith in working... because I was not 100% that my triangle way would have made a square.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `glOrtho(0, 640, 0, 480, 1, -1);` constructs a non-square viewport.  That means that the rendered output is more than likely going to be skewed if your window is not the same size as your viewport (or at least the same aspect ratio).

Consider the following comparison:

[image: ortho comparison]

If your viewport is the same size as your window, then it should remain square.  I'm using **JOGL**, but in my resize function, I reshape my viewport to be the new size of my window.

[image: Viewport as window size]

```
glcanvas.addGLEventListener(new GLEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable glautodrawable, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        GL2 gl = glautodrawable.getGL().getGL2();

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity(); // Resets any previous projection matrices
        gl.glOrtho(0, width, 0, height, 1, -1);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);
    }

    ... Other methods

}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your explanation is very good and i was able to make a square instead of a rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

To draw a square around the point `(x | y)` you can calculate the four points that represent the corners of your square.

First you'll need your width to height ratio

```
float ratio = width / height
```

I will use a `defaultSize` for the length of the shortest path from the midpoint to any of the sides.

Then you can calculate four values like so:

```
float a = x + defaultSize 
float b = ratio * (y + defaultSize) 
float c = x - defaultSize 
float d = ratio * (y - defaultSize)
```

with which you can represent all four corners to draw your square with. Since `GL_SQUAD` is deprecated I'll use `GL_TRIANGLE`.

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
glColor3f(red, green, blue);

// upper left triangle
glVertex2f(a, b);
glVertex2f(c, b);
glVertex2f(c, d);

 // lower right triangle
glVertex2f(a, b);
glVertex2f(c, d);
glVertex2f(a, d);

glEnd();
```

I don't know if this is the most performant or idiomatic way to do this since I just started exploring LWJGL.